# JAR-Level (Assembly-Level) Class Scoping in Java

Tags: java, jar

In C#, if I want a class to be visible to any class within that assembly (DLL), I simply scope it as `internal` (which is the default).

**How can I do this in Java?** In Java, I've noticed the default/internal scoping is *package level*, not *JAR level.* This is a problem for me, since I have a library that has several sub-packages with different responsibilities (view, controller, etc.) and can't put them in the same package.

As an example, I have two classes like `com.stackoverflow.main.first.One` and `com.stackoverflow.main.second.Two`, both of which should be able to instantiate each other.

**Edit:** I don't want the class to be `public` and visible from anyone who references it. It's an internal class *only*. I'm creating an API for consumption, and of primary importance to me is which classes can be seen by consumers of my JAR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish what you want, you'll have to use some mix of a factory pattern to create the classes you want to expose and leave the private classes package private. Usually, I've done this:

1. create the public interface for the API in a package like `com.foo.bar` a la `public interface Foo {}`
2. create a factory class that exposes a create method a la: 
   `public class FooFactory{ 
   public Foo buildFoo(){ return new FooImpl(); }`
3. create FooImpl as a package private class - `class FooImpl implements Foo{}`
4. Document package to indicate proper usage.

It's not perfect, but until the JSR about module scoping progresses, it's probably the closest you can get in java. If you want to ensure that FooImpl doesn't get inappropriately extended, be sure it is marked final.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your solution. Is `Foo` a class or an interface?

Comment: I apologize, I left off that Foo would be an interface and FooImpl would implement it.

Comment: I'd love to try it and then accept this as an answer. I have a feeling it'll work. Interfaces are not great, but I guess it'll do; either that, or I'll just have to make it public :/

Answer (score 3):

Java has no concept of library-level scoping.  Make the classes public or use a factory.

Comment: How would a factory solve the problem? If I implement, say, createInstance, I will still need to typecast or expose the type to the calling library.

Comment: Then your choice is clear - you need to use a factory of some description, and make the Factory public.  Which will make your hidden class accessible anyway.  To clarify - Classes can either be public or not public.  There is no other scoping applicable at the package level.

Answer (score 0):

sounds as simple as you have to use the public access modifier.