# How to avoid polluting API classes with internal methods?

Tags: java, access-modifiers, api-design

Background:

- In C#, you can have `internal` methods which are scoped to an assembly (JAR)
- Internal methods can be called by other classes in that assembly, but not outside.
- Java doesn't have any such analog.
- When creating an API, my internal methods have to be public so other parts of my API can call them.
- This pollutes my API, and potentially allows users to call internal methods.

TLDR: How can I indicate (or better yet, protect) my API's internal methods from being called by users outside my API classes, given that the methods are public?

Typical example:

```
  // public class in com.ashes999.components
  class SpriteComponent {
    // This method should be internal
    public void dispose() { ... } 
  }

  // public class in com.ashes999.management
  class SceneManager {
    public void changeScene(Scene s) {
      for (SpriteComponent s : this.allEntities.allSprites) {
        s.dispose();
      }
    }
  }
```

I would only ever call `SpriteComponent.dispose` from my own classes in `com.ashes999.*`. I would never, ever expect (or even desire) that other users would directly call it; doing so would cause chaos, havoc, mayhem, and unmanaged resources to be disposed prematurely, causing crashes.

Comment: You have package private access in Java.

Comment: "Package private"?  Such methods can be called by methods in other classes if they're in the same package, but not from other classes elsewhere.  A method is package-private if it doesn't have a `public`, `private`, or `protected` modifier.

Comment: Make them private or protected

Comment: Have you created the question twice?????

Comment: I have seen in some libraries (such as Apache Wicket) indicate in their documentation not to use / override certain methods, such as [HtmlSpecialTag](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.5/org/apache/wicket/markup/HtmlSpecialTag.html)

Comment: @MikeK that may be the only answer, although I'm hoping there's a better way.

Comment: Also, could [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7572009/jar-level-assembly-level-class-scoping-in-java) possibly help?

Comment: @MikeK epic fail... well done :)

Answer (score 4):

> A class may be declared with the modifier public, in which case that class is visible to all classes everywhere. **If a class has no modifier (the default, also known as package-private), it is visible only within its own package** (packages are named groups of related classes — you will learn about them in a later lesson.)
>
> **At the member level**, you can also use the public modifier **or no modifier (package-private)** just as with top-level classes, **and with the same meaning**. For members, there are two additional access modifiers: private and protected. The private modifier specifies that the member can only be accessed in its own class. The protected modifier specifies that the member can only be accessed within its own package (as with package-private) and, in addition, by a subclass of its class in another package.

([Access control](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html))

Comment: What happens then if you have two packages in your API, and two or more classes in different packages that need to use each others' methods? Wouldn't package-private scope cause issues?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding your answer. I added some  illustrative code. In this case, I have a public method in `com.ashes999.components` which I call from `com.ashes999.management`, but I have to make the method public; I can't make it package private, because the packages differ.

Comment: @MikeK If you have classes in different packages that need to access each others' methods, they should either be public or be in the same package. You have to choose.

Comment: @Eran this is the crux of my question. In C#, you don't have to choose, you just say "JAR-visible." Surely, I'm not the first person to miss this in Java, or the first person to look for the a work-around (documentation?) for this.

Comment: @ashes999 It seems that both mechanisms have their advantages and disadvantages.  I've heard from people who like Java's mechanism and think `internal` is useless.  What we probably want is a modifier like `public(com.ashes999.*)` that says "make this name visible to packages that match that pattern, and invisible everywhere else.  Java doesn't have anything like that, and AFAIK neither does C#.  So maybe we should convince one of the language teams to add this feature and hope the other one copies it.  :) :)

Comment: @ajb I won't debate this with you. C# implements something that is similar, which is like "everything in this jar can see internal methods on everything else in this jar." That's good enough for me.